# Itemized Annual Statement of Contributions

Tags: contributions

I can create a letter template containing the appropriate tokens from the Summary Fields but the only available token would be a Sum reflecting the entire year's donations. Is it possible to produce an end of the year statement that would reflect an itemized list of each individual contribution (including the final sum).

Comment: New features are added and bugs fixed in each release of CiviCRM, so please always include the version of CiviCRM you are using.  Also, there are sometimes CMS specific options for accomplishing tasks, so please always include your CMS and version in your question.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are using version 4.4 or higher the answer is yes.

In brief the steps are:

1. Use a Find Contributions search to identify the relevant contributions from last financial/fiscal year.
2. From the actions list select **Thank-you letters for Contributions**
3. Choose to **Group Contributions by** Contact.

More details, including layout of letters, can be found in the **Thank-you letters** section of the our [user and admin guide for version 4.6](http://gitbook.civicrm.org/contributions/everyday-tasks.html).  ( Functionality has been available since 4.4, but not documented until 4.6.)

Comment: Here's s link to a fuller  explanation http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/3269/257