# Donor wall in CiviCRM

Tags: extension

Does CiviCRM ship with or have an extension for a donor wall? If so, how well does it work? If not, what is a good solution for creating and managing a donor wall that will work with CiviCRM installed under WordPress?

Comment: I found this:   http://wiki.civicrm.org:8090/confluence/display/CRMDOC41/Donor+Wall   Does anyone use this?

Comment: Have you looked at http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/3254/setting-up-a-chinese-wall-anonymous-contributions ?

Comment: @JoAnne that ref is unrelated.  A donor wall lists donations a Chinese wall keeps things seperate.

Comment: Sorry, obviously I don't work in fundraising.  I will remember to ask for clarification in future.  Perhaps this is also a reminder that questioners should explain phrases that may be specific to their context.

Answer (score 1):

For wordpress I think you will have to write some custom development.  I tried to use a search profile for this but found it was lacking.  Perhaps you can figure it out but with drupal there are many possibilities.  The code reference is very old but may get you part way there.  I think this would be a great extension if you have funding.